# Error reindex catalog_product_attribute magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2, error

After running reindex catalog_product_attribute, I get an error - (General error: 1114 The table 'catalog_product_index_eav_temp' is full, query was: INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_index_eav_temp` SELECT`transit_catalog_product_index_eav_temp`de_`` _freq_emp`de_preduct_emalog `` FR_tem_ealog_em_`FRM_em_`*freem*`_freem_`_falog_pre__talog_preem_`)

Answer (score 0):

First check, if you did not run out of disk-space, before resolving to the configuration-related resolution.

You seem to have a too low maximum size for your `innodb_data_file_path` in your `my.cnf`, In this example

```
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:512M
```

you cannot host more than 512MB of data in all innodb tables combined.

Maybe you should switch to an innodb-per-table scheme using `innodb_file_per_table`.

[ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table is full](https://stackoverflow.com/a/730600/9956270)

Comment: It did not help